# Magnetic Field acting at a distance or near field induced ?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Are a magnetic's field lines of force due to mass acting at a distance or are there near field kinetic particles supplying the force along the lines of the field ?

Comment: Neither. Magnetic field lines are merely a mathematical abstraction for the measured forces. They give us a convenient way to talk about certain types of classical fields.

Comment: Then why when you heat the magnet and upset atomic structure and or randomize the mass of the magnet the lines of force in the field {or cumulative points of force as measured which equate to a mathematical abstraction} disappear ? Obviously the structure of the mass had something to due with mathematical abstraction or the field. So one would logically conclude that the mass of the magnet had something to due with the magnetic field it's existence or non-existence. And one would in turn naturally conclude the mass in proper alignment had acted at a distance.

Comment: One could also make the assumption there are also kinetic particles acting in the near field contributing to the immediate point of force. {Perhaps at right angles to an electric field.}

Comment: Field lines only describe the effective field of the magnet. To understand what's going on inside of ferromagnets, especially as a function of temperature, you need to use much more complicated theoretical tools and models from quantum mechanics and thermodynamics.